# Oracle contenido de una variable dinámica

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

Buenos días.

Tengo una tabla con 82 columnas en donde 80 de estas tienen por nombre col01, col02, col03,....col80. Realizo un fetch de la tabla y guardo los valores en vcol01, vcol02,...vcol80.

Lo que se requiere es poder identificar que columnas tienen valores y cuáles no. Para esto existen dos alternativas: 
a)preguntar por medio de if en cada columna si es nula o si tiene valor, la otra alternativa es 
b) en un while construir la variable vcol concatenado con una secuencia(vcol || secuencia) de tal forma que quede vcol01, vcol02, vcol03.... pero ahora requiero saber el contenido de ésta variable para saber si tiene valor o si es nula.

Para clarificar el tema comento lo siguiente: En la opción de hacer o construir 80 if es una alternativa que en sistemas se denomina a lo "bestia", por lo tanto no es una solución práctica. La otra alternativa es construir con un WHILE y construyendo una variable dinámica es decir si tenemos una secuencia = 1 y  utilizamos un 
While secuencia <= 80 then 
  begin
   xvar := 'vcol'||secuencia; 
   if xvar <> '' then
     .........
   end if;
  end;
  secuencia .= secuencia + 1;
  etc.....

Supongamos que vcol19 valga 123, luego xvar para secuencia 19 sera xvar:=vcol19, si preguntas por el valor de xvar, te retorna 'vcol19', pero lo que queremos NO es obtener para el contenido de XVAR sea VCOL19 sino el contenido de vcol19 es decir 123. Se desea no la definición de la VARIABLE DINÁMICA SINO EL CONTENIDO DE LA VARIABLE DINÁMICA, vuelvo a preguntar entonces: cómo se obtiene el contenido de una variable que fue construida de manera dinámica?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta especifica? ya tenes dos formas de hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor incluye un [mcve] para poder visualizar tu problemática. A veces, con palabras solamente, es difícil entender algo cuando uno está fuera de contexto.